# yii cgridview dropdownlist value

Tags: yii, cgridview

I am unable to set the value of the column day in the cgrid view :
I am able to see the dropdownlist but all have the same day Monday set irrespective of the value of the day as represented by $data->day

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'type'=>'raw',
            'name'=>'day',
        'value'=> ' CHtml::dropDownList(\'someName\'.$row,\'$data->day\',array(
                    \'Mo\'=>\'Monday\',
                    \'Tu\'=>\'Tuesday\',
                    \'We\'=>\'Wednesday\',
                    \'Th\'=>\'Thursday\',
                   \'Fr\'=>\'Friday\',
                   \'Sa\'=>\'Saturday\',
                   \'Su\'=>\'Sunday\',))',  

                ),
            'ts_id'
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Why are you scaping the `'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor issue resolved the whole episode.
I had put quotes around $data->day in the original post. which was not needed.

```
   array(  'type'=>'raw',
            'name'=>'day',
            'value'=> ' CHtml::dropDownList(\'someName\'.$row,$data->day,
             array(\'Mo\'=>\'Monday\',
                        \'Tu\'=>\'Tuesday\',
                        \'We\'=>\'Wednesday\',
                        \'Th\'=>\'Thursday\',
                       \'Fr\'=>\'Friday\',
                       \'Sa\'=>\'Saturday\',
                       \'Su\'=>\'Sunday\',)
              )',  
     ),
```

Comment: If you have php 5.3 you could use anonymous function for `value`, it is much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

If you can accept a minor break in MVC then things will get much easier to read if you put a little getter method into your model:

```
public function getDayDropDown()
{
    $days = array('Mo'=>'Monday', ...);
    return CHtml::dropDownList('someName', $this->day, $days);
}
```

Now in your gridview you can use it as a column like

```
array(
    'name' => 'Day',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value' => '$data->dayDropDown',
),
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but still got all mondays only.  So I put a log to see what is the CHtml returning, this is what I got:     <select name="someName" id="someName">
    <option value="Mo">Monday</option>
    <option value="To">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="We">Wednsday</option>
    <option value="Th">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Fr">Friday</option>
    <option value="Sa">Saturday</option>
    <option value="Su">Sunday</option>
    </select>

Comment: Then the values you get from DB do not match any of your select options. Verify that your DB values use the same case ("Mo" not "mo").  If in doubt, just output the current DB value with `$data->day` in your grid.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of dropdown value and update onchange:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id'=>'session-grid',
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider'=>$PSDataProvider,
    'filter'=>$PSModel,
    'emptyText'=>'No hay sesiones abiertas.',
    'columns'=>array(
        array('name'=>'username', 'header'=>'Nombre de Usuario', 'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($PSModel, 'username', 
                 array('placeholder'=>'Buscar por usuario...'))),
        array('name'=>'product', 'header'=>'Producto', 'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($PSModel, 'product', 
                 array('placeholder'=>'Buscar por producto...'))),
        array('name'=>'expire', 'value'=>'date("d-m-y H:i:s", $data->expire)','header'=>'Hora de Expiracion', 'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($PSModel, 'expire', 
                 array('placeholder'=>'Buscar por expiracion...'))),
        array(
          'header'=>CHtml::dropDownList('pageSize',$pageSize,array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,50=>50),array(
            'onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiGridView.update('session-grid',{ data:{pageSize: $(this).val() }})",
            'class'=>'span1 custom-tb-dropdown-inline',
          )),
          'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
          'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px'),
          'template'=>'{delete}',
          'buttons'=>array(            
            'delete' => array(
              'label'=>'Terminar sesión',
            ),
          ),
          'deleteConfirmation'=>'Está seguro que desea terminar la sesión seleccionada?',
          'deleteButtonUrl'=>'$this->grid->owner->createUrl("productSession/delete", $data->primaryKey)'
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: I am not able to get the value to be selected in the drop down list, I am getting all mondays only.

Comment: Jorge, this is something else. In your code you have dropdown in header, while @friedFingers wants a dropdown grid cell.